# How to keep a stronger reference of a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

the problem is that the image i want to show fist stays in the middle of the screen during the entire scrolling proccess obscuring the rest of the views contents. Any fixes ? My storyboard had a UIScrollView > list view and over it a UIImage connected to IBOutlets. Here is the rest of the code. Thanks.

```
 UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pcat3.png"]];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,300)];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
[self->listView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: How did you instantiate your scroll view?

Comment: thanks for your reply. edit above. the output has changed a little bit

Comment: I am using this program. Please bear with me to read it. The details for the stream are listed in stream screen. m http://www.raywenderlich.com/13541/how-to-create-an-app-like-instagram-with-a-web-service-backend-part-22